# Regex match unique numbers delimited by semicolon

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find out the regular expression for the following input and rules:

- String contains only digits (1-9 and 10) and semicolon ";" character as a delimiter
- The amount of values can be from 1 to 4
- Values must be unique

I created the following expression:

```
^([1-9]|10)(;([1-9]|10)){0,3}$
```

which covers everything except uniqueness of numbers.

Valid examples:

```
1;10
4;3
2
1;2;3;4
10;5;1
```

Invalid examples:

```
10;2;35
1,2,3
7*5;4
;4
1;;2
46
8;10;8
2;1;2 (this one doesn't currently work)
```

Any advice on how I can match only when values are unique?

Comment: I don't think regex is the best tool for this, though it should be possible. Which tool/language are you using? A valid answer might depend on it.

Comment: Java. Well if there's no way, of course I can handle it via code, but out of curiosity I was wondering if there's a way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add negative look aheads, which use back references, to enforce uniqueness:

```
^([1-9]|10)(?!.*\b\1\b)(;([1-9]|10)(?!.*\b\3\b)){0,3}$
```

The word boundaries `\b` are needed to prevent `1` from matching `10`.

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/GnWbI9ttZC) using your examples.